# How to handle complete form submission in React JS instead of using onChange handlers for each field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per React demo and other samples, I see everyone attaching an **onChange** eventhandler to each form field they want to store.

I don't want to onChange or other events to keep executing until the form is actually submitted.
I want to access and setState on form submit (handleSubmit) handler.

*This is react's demo*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add refs to the input fields, remove value and onChange attributes from the input tags and read those values in your handleSubmit function. You could do that, but it's not very reactive.